# Optimize Oracle query with joins and multiple selects

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running a query that takes 6-7 seconds to run in an IDE, and 4-5x that long when I run it via a Confluence plugin to publish results to a wiki.  I'm fairly new to to Oracle and the Over / Partition By section was something I learned from researching on Stack Overflow.  It gets me the results I'm looking for, but not fast enough.

What I'm trying to achieve:
We have a test repository.  Each test gets run multiple times a day.  I need the most recent execution status, execution date and other related values for each test. The query only returns 4k records so I don't think it should take as long as it does.  When it takes upwards of 30 seconds to display on the wiki (where we need to publish results, it's very inefficient.

I'm hoping someone can take a look and help me optimize this and help me understand what the solution is. Breaking it down and running individually, the speed issue is definitely with the over/partition by section.

Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT
TS_USER_11                               AS "Team",
TS_TEST_ID                               AS "Test ID",
TS_NAME                                  AS "Test Name",
TS_USER_06                               AS "Priority",

CASE  
WHEN RN_STATUS = 'Failed' OR RN_STATUS = 'Issue Found' THEN 'Ran with Issues'
WHEN RN_STATUS = 'No Run' AND RN_EXECUTION_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'Skipped'
WHEN (RN_STATUS = 'No Run' OR RN_STATUS = 'N/A') AND RN_EXECUTION_DATE IS NULL THEN 'Not Run'
    ELSE RN_STATUS END                       AS "Exec Status",

TS_USER_03                               AS "Type",
TO_CHAR(RN_EXECUTION_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Execution Date",
RN_USER_01                               AS "Build Number"

FROM

(SELECT
  TS_NAME,
  TS_USER_11,
  TS_USER_06,
  TS_TEST_ID,
  TS_USER_03,
  RN_RUN_ID,
  RN_USER_01,
  max(RN_RUN_ID)

OVER
(
  PARTITION BY RN_TEST_CONFIG_ID ) last_run_id,
  RUN.RN_STATUS,
  RUN.RN_EXECUTION_DATE

FROM DATA_PROTECTION_HENDRIX_DB.RUN
LEFT JOIN DATA_PROTECTION_HENDRIX_DB.TEST ON RN_TEST_ID = TS_TEST_ID
LEFT JOIN DATA_PROTECTION_HENDRIX_DB.ALL_LISTS ON AL_ITEM_ID = TS_SUBJECT

WHERE (ALL_LISTS.AL_ABSOLUTE_PATH NOT LIKE 'AAAAAPAAJ%' AND ALL_LISTS.AL_ABSOLUTE_PATH NOT LIKE 'AAAAAPAAC%')  AND
     (TS_TEMPLATE IS NULL OR TS_TEMPLATE = 'N')
)

WHERE RN_RUN_ID = last_run_id
```

Comment: I know you're saying the performance through the plugin is unacceptable? But are you also saying the 6-7s through IDE is excessive as well? Will you please share the query plan? The query plan should contain other details required to assist such as indexes used, stats, etc.

Comment: Hi - I think if I can decrease the time in the IDE, it will help decrease time through the plugin.  

How do I obtain a query plan? I can see, using DataGrip, that the response time is:
3264 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 6s 368ms (execution 4s 934ms, fetching 1s 434ms)

I was reading about indexes yesterday but wasn't entirely clear how to use them.

I also tried using the Oracle SQL Developer Tuning Advisor but it didn't provide any recommendations or info.

Comment: I don't understand your thinking. If a query takes 6 seconds in an IDE and 30 seconds to run over a plugin... the extra 24 seconds is **fully** attributable to factors external to the running of the query in the database server. So, if you can reduce the run time of your query in the IDE from 6 seconds to 2 seconds, the time through the plugin will drop from 30 seconds to 26 seconds - not to 10 seconds. So - aren't you looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Other than that, it seems RN_RUN_ID is the primary key in one of your tables, and you need to retrieve rows with the highest RN_RUN_ID for each group (partition) by RN_TEST_CONFIG_ID? In that case, you can improve speed (but only within limits!) if instead of the analytic function approach you are using, you would use the FIRST/LAST **aggregate** function: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions065.htm#SQLRF00641

Comment: I see your point about the IDE vs plugin speed as you've described it, and it makes sense.  I think if I stepped away from the pressure to get this done I would have made that connection eventually. 

I will take a look at the aggregate function and see if it works more efficiently or the answer provided by Thangamani.  Thank you for taking the time to respond.  I do appreciate it.  As a newbie, we can read all we can but sometimes we still need help pointing us in the right direction.

Comment: This article explains how to use features like DBMS_XPLAN, et al, to display query plans: https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/how-do-i-display-and-read-the-execution-plans-for-a-sql-statement .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have indices on `(Run.rn_test_config_id, Run.rn_run_id)` *AND* `(Run.rn_run_id)`, which should help with the partitioning and subsequent join.

I'd also probably see if tweaking your query like this would help:

```
SELECT  Test.ts_user_11 AS "Team", 
        Test.ts_test_id AS "Test ID",
        Test.ts_name AS "Test Name",
        TEST.ts_user_06 AS "Priority",
        CASE WHEN Run.rn_status = 'Failed' OR Run.rn_status = 'Issue Found' 
                  THEN 'Ran with Issues'
             WHEN Run.rn_status = 'No Run' AND Run.rn_execution_date IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN 'Skipped'
             WHEN (Run.rn_status = 'No Run' OR Run.rn_status = 'N/A') AND Run.rn_execution_date IS NULL 
                  THEN 'Not Run'
             ELSE Run.rn_status END AS "Exec Status",
        Test.ts_user_03 AS "Type",
        TO_CHAR(Run.rn_execution_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Execution Date",
        Run.rn_user_01 AS "Build Number"  
FROM Data_Protection_Hendrix_DB.Run Run
-- one of the few times you can exclude the grouping condition from the results!
-- Only since rn_run_id is distinct
JOIN (SELECT MAX(rn_run_id) AS run_id
      FROM Data_Protection_Hendrix_DB.Run
      GROUP BY rn_test_config_id) Latest_Run
  ON Latest_Run.run_id = Run.rn_run_id
-- kept these as a LEFT JOIN, since that's more likely the intent.
-- I'm not sure that's what you were _getting_, though.
LEFT JOIN Data_Protection_Hendrix_DB.Test
       ON Test.ts_test_id = Run.rn_test_id
          AND Test.ts_template = 'N'
LEFT JOIN Data_Protection_Hendrix_DB.All_Lists
       ON All_Lists.al_item_id = Test.ts_subject
          AND All_Lists.al_absolute_path NOT LIKE 'AAAAAPAAJ%'
          AND All_Lists.al_absolute_path NOT LIKE 'AAAAAPAAC%'
```

Comment: Thank you!  On first try, it's only returning the status and date and null's for everything else.  I'll take a look at it and see if I can figure out why...

Comment: Hm, possibly take heed of my second comment inside the code, and switch from `LEFT JOIN` to a regular (inner) `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping you should have a proper index for joining, also to avoid compare with too many records, i just used first table(run) to identify only that what needed and then join with other table.

this below sql may help you, i am not sure, just let me know if it does.

Thanks
Thangamani Eraniyan.

[image]

```
SELECT
    TS_USER_11                               AS "Team",
    TS_TEST_ID                               AS "Test ID",
    TS_NAME                                  AS "Test Name",
    TS_USER_06                               AS "Priority",
    CASE  
        WHEN RN_STATUS = 'Failed' OR RN_STATUS = 'Issue Found' THEN 'Ran with Issues'
        WHEN RN_STATUS = 'No Run' AND RN_EXECUTION_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'Skipped'
        WHEN (RN_STATUS = 'No Run' OR RN_STATUS = 'N/A') AND RN_EXECUTION_DATE IS NULL THEN 'Not Run'
            ELSE RN_STATUS 
    END                       AS "Exec Status",       
    TS_USER_03                               AS "Type",
    TO_CHAR(RN_EXECUTION_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Execution Date",
    RN_USER_01                               AS "Build Number"
    RN_RUN_ID,
FROM (SELECT RN_RUN_ID,
             RN_USER_01,
             row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY RN_TEST_CONFIG_ID order by RN_RUN_ID desc  /* or if you have any run dt  desc*/  ) lno,
             RUN.RN_STATUS,
             RUN.RN_EXECUTION_DATE
       FROM  DATA_PROTECTION_HENDRIX_DB.RUN
     ) RUN 
LEFT JOIN DATA_PROTECTION_HENDRIX_DB.TEST ON RUN.RN_TEST_ID = TS_TEST_ID
LEFT JOIN DATA_PROTECTION_HENDRIX_DB.ALL_LISTS ON AL_ITEM_ID = TS_SUBJECT
WHERE RUN.LNO =1 
     (ALL_LISTS.AL_ABSOLUTE_PATH NOT LIKE 'AAAAAPAAJ%' AND ALL_LISTS.AL_ABSOLUTE_PATH NOT LIKE 'AAAAAPAAC%')  AND
     NVL(TS_TEMPLATE ,'N') = 'N'
```